# Salesforce Knowledge user permission

Tags: knowledge

When Knowledge Article is enabled on Cases, the user can attach the article to the cases. I want to stop user from being able to attach the article to the case. I just want to show them the suggested article which they can refer, but not be able to attach to the case itself.